# jqassistant tool how query java method belongs to class

Tags: java, jqassistant

I am using a Java plugin and I am querying the calling link of a java method to find out which java class the method belongs to, how to query that, or which property identifier it belongs to.

For example, I want to know which Demo1 or Demo2 class the hello method belongs to and how to find it

```
class Demo1{

public void hello(){



}

}



class Demo2{

public void hello(){



}

}
```

How to query or use

Answer (score 0):

There is a `DECLARES` relation between a class member (i.e. `:Field` or `:Method`) and its enclosing type:

```
MATCH
  (t:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
WHERE
  m.name = 'hello'
RETURN
  t.fqn, m.signature
```

Comment: thx
I want to find the call chain for Java methods.
such as:

Demo#hello()---->Demo#hello2()

But currently, I have found that method types in Neo4j do not store associated class information. How to handle methods with different classes and the same name